# How to use a pre-filled database for IONIC?

Tags: sqlite, ionic-framework, mobile, ionic3

I am new to IONIC. I want to know what is the ideal choice for storage. Is it IONIC storage?

Also i need to manually enter some data for the app. Now i can’t find any way to store data beforehand, is this possible in ionic?

For example, lets say i need a database/storage filled before with some values. How can i do that? Is that possible or i need to get the data from cloud?

I have posted my query in IONIC forum, this is the best answer i got:

> Super simple solution: On start you check if a special value is set, e.g. databasePreloaded. If it is missing, you open a file, read the content and write it to the storage. Then you set databasePreloaded. On next start it will be present and the data won’t be loaded again.

My question is if the data is around 5-6 MB then what the ideal way to do that?

Answer (score 0):

Using a check to see if the data has been loaded is a simple choice.

It would be easy to work with.

The main issue for me is whether the data will change at all once it has been deployed? You would need to think how this would be handled.

Finally, I'm under the impression IndexedDB can only handle up to 5mb so you will need to store this data in sqlite?